# SFML и filesystem

Tags: windows, файловая-система, mingw, sfml

Писал я на линуксе небольшую игру, sfml и filesystem. Все было норм, пока я не вспомнил, что запускать ее надо бы на винде.а в винде я не могу заставить их работать вместе, пользуюсь eclipse и mingw. Filesystem работает только с mingw 8+, а sfml только с 7.3-
Как их заставить вместе работать, мб другой компилятор использовать. Скомпилировать sfml на mingw8+ тоже не выходит, выбивает ошибки, не может графику скомпилировать

Answer (score 0):

В общем сам нашел способ обойти это. В библиотеке boost есть такой же filesystem, но предназначенная для с++11